# How to provide an editable column feature for python dash for to_html dataframe?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, plotly-dash

I've written the following code which creates an HTML file 'data.html'. This file only displays a data table using dash. There are six columns out of which I'd like to keep one column 'colH' editable here in logic itself. For normal dataframes it is easy to provide a parameter - 'editable = True' however I've been struggling to incorporate it for to_html dataframe here.

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from IPython.core.display import display,HTML
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect
import webbrowser
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import os

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)
MP = 'GB'

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (1, 'Hello', 158, True, 'Extract-Text-from-Image-using-Python-840x400',""),
        (2, 'Hey', 567, False, 'sampletext1-ocr',""),
        (3, 'Hi', 123, False, 'sampletext2-ocr',""),
        (4, 'Howdy', 578, True, 'sampletext3-ocr',""),
        (5, 'Hello', 418, True, 'image-10',""),
        (6, 'Hi', 98, False, 'image-9',""),
    ],
    columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE', 'colH']
)


def categorise(row):
    return f"https://pyshark.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/{row['colE']}.png"

df['colF'] = df.apply(lambda row: categorise(row), axis=1)

images1 = df['colF'].values.tolist()
df['colG'] = images1

# convert your links to html tags 
def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="60" >'

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

image_cols = ['colG']  #<- define which columns will be used to convert to html

# Create the dictionary to be passed as formatters
format_dict = {}
for image_col in image_cols:
    format_dict[image_col] = path_to_image_html

a = HTML(df.drop(['colF'], axis=1).to_html(escape=False ,formatters=format_dict))

with open("assets/data.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(a.data)
```

[Output generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q7JL.png)

How to make just 'colH' editable here?

Comment: There is no dash code, here!

Comment: But I've made this from https://dash.plotly.com/ documentation.

Comment: You did this by `IPython.core.display.HTML` . If you want to create editable table or columns in dash read this https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/editable